# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using WICD?

Tags: wireless, networking

I've been wondering on what are the advantages and disadvantages of WICD

Can somebody please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably sum this up as:

> Advantages:
>
> - It replaces Network Manager
>
> Disadvantages:
>
> - It replaces Network Manager

They both aim to do the same job and they're roughly a [drop-in replacement](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) for each other. Some people prefer WICD because of its ncurses command line UI and others prefer to stick with NM because of its default status in most distributions and it *does* seem to be well maintained and improved.

The only times I've ever seen somebody switch from NM is when NM can't or won't do something they need. If you don't *need* WICD, I wouldn't suggest changing over.

Answer (score 0):

One small advantage of WICD over NM is that it gives more information on what's going on. 
I use to have a problem that my wireless couldn't connect; With NM, I only see that NM tries to connect, then it says fail to connect, then automatically reconnect, then fail again, then reconnect, ..., it keeps going that way without me knowing why exactly it failed. With WICD, I can see the connection attempt is stuck at "Obtaining IP address". So at least with WICD, if there is a problem, I can see what the problem is.